# How to write dataframe to csv to the current working directory python

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, getcwd

My code would be something like this:

```py
  import os
  import pandas as pd
  cwd = os.getcwd()
  csv_name = '/CONTCAR_SORTED'
  df = pd.read_csv(f"{cwd}{csv_name}",
                 skiprows=2, nrows=100, names=['X','Y','Z' ], 
                 delimiter='\s+',engine='python')

  df=df.to_csv("new")
```

In this way, the output file is written in the directory where the executed python script is located. I have tried different ways to specify a different folder but no file is written in those cases. I don't know how to pass and change to another path to the destination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
path = cwd + "/new"
df.to_csv(path)
```

Your file will be stored in the working directory with the name 'new'.

Comment: I need to run the script in different folders in a way such that once it is executed the output file is written in the current working directory, so that I do not have to insert and modify manually the path in code everytime! I was not able to apply your method in the case where part of the path is a string   cwd = os.getcwd().

Comment: Please look at my edit. That way the file will always be stored in the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Writing dataframe to CSV file is documented here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

In every python module there is a variable `__file__` which has the absolute path for the current python module. You can use it to write CSV to where that python file is located.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the path and pass it to to_csv method.

```
df.to_csv(os.path.join(cwd, "new"))
```